# I am facing this error in python "not all arguments converted during string formatting" while writing a code for converting two list within one list

Tags: python

In this code specifically I am getting error while using modulus with 'i'.

```
def fun(l):
    even=[]
    odd=[]
    for i in l:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even.append(i)
        else:  
            odd.append(i)  

    total=[]
    total.append(odd,even)        
    return total

numbers=['2','3','4','5','7'] 
print(fun(numbers))
```

ERROR:

```
File "e:\python codes\lists\ex4.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(fun(numbers))
  File "e:\python codes\lists\ex4.py", line 5, in fun
    if i % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Your list elements are **strings** - you try a `if string % 2 == 0:`   ... see [% string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a list of strings instead of a list of numbers. When you apply the `%` operator to a string it performs string formatting. What you probably wanted to do was

```
numbers=[2,3,4,5,7]
```

Additionally your line

```
total.append(odd,even)
```

will give an error as `append` only takes a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments in your list are currently strings, so they're being treated as strings instead of integers.

You have two options:

- 1. change the input to integers as follows:

`numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]`

- 2. convert your strings within your function:

```
def fun(l): 
   ...
   for i in l:
      if type(i) == str:
         if int(i) % 2 == 0:
         ...
      else:
           i % 2 == 0:
           ...
      ...
```

The second method could lead to various problems with mutation, and also doesn't have very good readability. I would go with the first.

Also, make sure to use:
`total = [even, odd]`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you would want to use a list of integers instead of strings.
Then `append` takes only one parameter instead of two.

Splitting

```
 total.append(odd, even)
```

into

```
 total.append(odd)        
 total.append(even)
```

will give the desired result: `[[3, 5, 7], [2, 4]]`.